# Pass a variable to "tell application"?

Tags: macos, applescript

How can i pass a variable to  `tell application currentWindow` in Applescript?

I have this code:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set currentWindow to get name of processes whose frontmost is true
end tell

-- get bundle identifier of (info for (path to application currentWindow)) -- KO
-- tell application id currentWindow -- KO
-- tell application "Finder" -- ok
tell application currentWindow -- KO!
    activate
end tell
```

I want to open `currentWindow`, of course, without know the name.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adayzdone has the better method, however the main problem with your code is that currentWindow is a list of names {"front application name"}. You're asking for "name of processes", plural, and get the results back in a list. So since it's a list, you have to access the items of the list. Therefore this would probably work. You'll notice adayzdone asks for the "first application process" and therefore he gets only 1 result and then it's not a list.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set currentWindow to get name of processes whose frontmost is true
end tell

tell application (item 1 of currentWindow)
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: It works when the target front applicate exists in process list only.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
tell application "System Events" to set frontBundleId to bundle identifier of first application process whose frontmost is true
tell application id frontBundleId to activate
```